# Jquery: Hide list elements if they go off the screen

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, list

I have a list of icons that is going to be my navigation down the left hand side of the page.
The navigation is set to be 100% of the height of the page.

If in the future I wish to add more icons to the list and they end up going off the page, I wish to hide the overlapping icons and have buttons to hide the currently visible x number of icons and show the second x number of icons.

Basically my question for now is: *if a list of items is overflowing off the screen, how can I find the elements that do not fit and hide them?*

Comment: You'll need to find each elements position relative to the window, and calculate wether or not the element is inside the visible screen.

Answer (score 0):

You can get an element's [`offset()`](http://api.jquery.com/offset/) and compare it to the width of the window.

So for example, if you have a vertical list of icons and want to know if the are visible:

```
$('nav a').each(function(index)() {
    if ($(this).offset().top > $(window).height()) {
        $(this).hide();
    }
});
```

Answer (score 0):

you can achieve it by css. It will not hide the element but would not show on screen, it is faster than finding all elements and hiding them:

```
.leftNav{
   height:80px;  
   overflow-y: hidden;
   border-style:solid;
   border-width:1px;
}
```

html:

```
<div class='leftNav'>
   <div>nav 1</div>
   <div>nav 2</div>
   <div>nav 3</div>
    .
    .
    .
</div>
```

[Working Demo](http://jsfiddle.net/YzhdY/1/)

css:

```
  overflow-y: auto;
```

can be used to show scrollbar [Demo](http://jsfiddle.net/YzhdY/3/)